# CloudDeploy broken with neural net (new)

Tags: neural-networks, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

over the last few weeks I routinely deployed neural nets to the cloud for computation. Today, even the simplest example does not work anymore:

```
(*initialise random neural net that talkes 200x200 image as input*)
scrnet = NetInitialize@
  NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[1, 1], PartLayer[1]}, 
   "Input" -> {1, 200, 200}]

(*Deploy to cloud*)
cnet = CloudExport[scrnet, "MX", Permissions -> "Public"];

(*test on example image *WORKS**)
img = Import["ExampleData/ocelot.jpg"];
With[{net = CloudImport@cnet}, Image@net@{ImageData@img}]

(*Deploy as cloud form page *)
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage[{"image" -> "Image"}, 
  With[{net = CloudImport@cnet}, Image@net@{ImageData@#image}] &], 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

The last piece of code generates a cloud object. If I try to upload the ocelot image I get `Image[Failed]` as the sole output. If I do not use a net the form works fine:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage[{"image" -> "Image"}, Image@ImageData@#image &], 
   Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Should I contact wolfram support or am I doing something wrong? I have ~1000 cloud credits left on a free account so that should not be the issue.

EDIT: Could it be related to my licence? I am on the free plan for the development platform which claims that "some" functions are restricted.

Best,
Max

Comment: Huh. I'm not aware of any issue like this. A simple non-image Netchain works fine. 
```
scrnet = NetInitialize@NetChain[{ElementwiseLayer[Ramp]}];
cnet = CloudExport[scrnet, "MX", Permissions -> "Public"];
FormPage["nums" -> DelimitedSequence["Real"], 
 With[{net = CloudImport@cnet}, {net@#nums, #nums} &]]
```
when you supply it with input like "1,0,2"

Comment: Also, this NetChain seems to work fine in a notebook on Mathematica Online, so it's probably not some kind of strange compatibility issue. You've got me stumped. I guess I should try to capture what errors are happening

Comment: You mean you can ClodDeploy[] the conv net from mathematica online but not from the desktop version?

Comment: No. The Netchain works both in Desktop Mathematica and in a notebook on Mathematica Online. So it's pretty mysterious to me why it's returning $Failed. I'm asking around and filing a bug report, but you might want to report this Wolfram Tech Support so you can get a ticket number etc.

Comment: How do I reach tech support? I was just told by support to post the problem to the community while I don't see how that would help now.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know who could have suggested you do that instead of contact tech support. You can contact them thru this form: 
https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/
Make it clear you want to file a bug.

Comment: So maybe there's a version difference between the functionality you have and the cloud version. ```PacletInformation["NeuralNetworks"] // Lookup["Version"]``` This ideally will give 11.3.5, but might give 11.3.4 if the paclet hasn't updated.  What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems as if ImageData is used differently on my desktop compared to the cloud. The following alteration works:

```
scrnet = NetInitialize@
  NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[1, 1], PartLayer[1]}, 
   "Input" -> {1, 200, 200, 3}]
cnet = CloudExport[scrnet, "MX", "scrnet", Permissions -> "Public"]
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage[{"image" -> "Image"}, 
  With[{net = CloudImport@cnet}, Image@net@{ImageData@#image}] &], 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Funny enough the following does not work:

```
With[{net = CloudImport@cnet}, Image@net@{ImageData@img}]
```

It seems that ImageData on my desktop converts RGB to greyscale but does not do that in the cloud.

EDIT: As people stated correctly in the comments the issue was not with ImageData[] but rather with the way the image was saved. Thanks to everyone!

Max

Comment: If I create Form that does (ImageData // Dimensions), I consistently see RGB output that looks like ```{_,_,3}```.  Both in Mathematica and in the cloud. I think the issue is how the NetChain handles this.

Comment: So the issue is that original image is greyscale, but if you save it or do anything to it, it'll be converted into a different colorspace. In this case, you're converting it from grayscale into an RGB colorspace so the dimensionality of the image changes. This really confused me too, but I don't think it's a bug of any kind. The correct solution for this is probably to use NetEncoder for Images to make the NetChain be more universal in the kind of input it accepts.